Lifting of elements in Weyl groups of $B_2$ and $C_2$ type
It is well known that given a maximal torus $T$ in a linear Lie group $G$, the corresponding Weyl group can be defined as $N_G(T)/T$. As the title suggests, I am now working on the Weyl groups of $B_2$ and $C_2$ types, both of which are isomorphic to the dihedral group
$$
D(4)=\langle r,s:r^4=s^2=1,srs=r^{-1}\rangle.
$$
Now I need to find a representative of $r\in W$, viewed as an element in the quotient group described above, in the two matrix Lie groups $\mathrm{SO}(5)$ and $\mathrm{Sp}(4)$. How can I do it? Thanks for your help.

By $SO(5)$ and $Sp(4)$, do you mean the complex Lie groups? Because in the compact real ones, there will be nothing to find.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, indeed. We are talking about complex case.

I think I have found out how to do. Will update this post soon if possible.
